# 1 pixel of background repeat during zoom in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have faced really strange problem in google chrome (desktop and mobile). Here is [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jFe6E/). 
If you zoom in till 500% you ll see green line at the top of the div. It seems that background image repeats itself. The green line is the bottom line of my background image, if I make background image bottom transparent the line it disappears. I added repeat-x in my css but it still repeats 1 pixel of my image:

```
background: url('') repeat-x;
```

Comment: I see this issue most often in Android devices. And now zooming `background-image`s is broken on desktop Chrome as well.

Comment: If i remember right it is a _repeating_  bug where you see the bottom of the image. You should be able to fix this by moving the image half a pixel up `background-position:  left -0.5px;`. But then you need to add one pixel at the bottom. (But i can't test right now if i remember it right ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract 1px from everything, including the background x-position.

```
.red-div{
    background-color: red;
    height: 29px;
    width: 300px;
}

.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('') repeat-x;
    background-position:-1px 100%;

}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jFe6E/7/)